# Entered a number as int, but it outputs not the same (returns 256)

Tags: c++, types, integer

The following is my C++ code for entering integer numbers that have three figures.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    char b[3];

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    cout << a << " " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Input :

```
472
385
```

Result :

```
256 385
```

I tried entered the two numbers of 472 and 385, but it returns 256 and 385.
Why is `a` changed to 256?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do note, that, when reading `b`, the value of `385` requires 4 characters of storage, while `b` contains only 3. Hence, such a program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Buffer overflow strikes again: you're reading 4 chars (inc. null terminator) into a 3 length array.

Comment: You have `#include <string>`, but didn't use `std::string`.  If you had used `std::string b;`, then you wouldn't have had the issue you're seeing now.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I wrote b[4] and could get right result. Actually I can't understand why char[] should have 4 spaces, but I'll try study more.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In fact, these are just part of my whole codes. I should calculate by using each seperated figures of `b`, so it was a trace of my trials.

Comment: @Kimpro The flaw in the function is that anyone can enter any amount of characters, regardless of how big you make the `char` array.  If you make it 4 characters, what stops the user from entering more than 4 characters?  Nothing.  That's why using `std::string` is preferred and prevents buffer overflows from occurring on input.

Comment: Or, at least use `cin.get()` instead of `cin >>` when reading into a `char[]`, so that you can pass in the `char[]`'s size so the read won't overflow.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This was a coding problem where the figures of the numbers were given condition. But, of course, I want to make my codes more generalized. I will try it!

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you I will also try  `cin.get()`!